# Suitable XML Marshaller and Unmarshaller

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, xstream, unmarshalling

We have an XML that needs to be converted to an object and vice versa. Something like Xstream does. Until now we were using Xstream to marshall and unmarshall the object/xml. 
However the problem is that an object that corresponds to XML in xstream, needs to have all the tags as attributes; else if XML contains any extra tags which are not present in object; it bombs.

Or, we need to have custom convertors written to make sure that the operation goes as desired. I was also suggested that common digester allows Xpath parsing from XML to an object.

I am wondering what is the best approach; as long as:

1. I just want to convert XML to Object and vice versa.
2. Have the ability to silently ignore any fields in XML that map not be present in mapping object.

What do you suggest?

Comment: +1: This is important when dealing with multiple versions of the data.  Assuming the new version just has more attributes and is otherwise backward compatible with software that expects the old version, you'd like the new XML to be unmarshalled into an old object.

You'd like a client that expects an older version of the object with fewer attributes to be able to be unmarshalled from XML that was

Comment: I understand your point and that is my intent too. However is there a framework which is capable of doing it with least effort. Like I said, in Stream I'll have to write converters. Is there something else; which helps on this aspect more seamlessly. I am not aware of all the frameworks out there which can help in doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this question...

[What is the best way to convert a java object to xml with open source apis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736343/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-java-object-to-xml-with-open-source-apis)

These are some of the libraries that it lists...

- http://simple.sourceforge.net/
- [http://x-stream.github.io/](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)
- http://xmlbeans.apache.org/
- http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0470.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a custom MapperWrapper as documented here http://pvoss.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/xstream/

```
XStream xstream = new XStream() {
  @Override
  protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
    return new MapperWrapper(next) {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldSerializeMember(Class definedIn,
              String fieldName) {
        if (definedIn == Object.class) {
          return false;
        }
        return super.shouldSerializeMember(definedIn, fieldName);
      }
    };
  }
};
```

The only thing it does is tell XStream to ignore all fields that it does not know to deal with.

Comment: Or you could use JAXB that gives the desired behavior by default.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using http://simple.sourceforge.net/ I uses annotations to map attributes and elements and has a "non strict" mode which enables you to read from the XML document ignoring all attributes and elements not present in the Java object.

Comment: Why use a proprietary solution like Simple, when you could use and industry standard like JAXB, http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jaxb-xml-binding-standard.html

Comment: I think you misunderstand the word proprietary, Simple has a more liberal license (Apache). Also, you can do more with Simple than you can with JAXB. Finally its easier to use, faster, more light weight, and works on Andriod, GAE, and any Java 1.5+ VM.