# JAXB Performance

Tags: xml, jaxb

In my current project I have a requirement where I need to build an xml document. I am planning to go with JAXB by creating the Java domain classes and marshall it into XML. IS this an efficient approach? If not can you suggest any better approaches for XML building?

Answer (score 4):

See [ivan-ivanovich-ivanoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76393/ivan-ivanovich-ivanoff)'s answer to a [similar question posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736343/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-java-object-to-xml-with-open-source-apis). The short answer is that JAXB is going to be the best approach.