# Message between object tags in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class called Claim,

```
public class Claim {
      List<Data> datas;
      //getter and setter
}
```

And a dependency class Data:

```
public class Data {
  String type;
  String description;
  //getter and setter 
}
```

I want the to generate XML in the following format:

```
<claim>
   <dta type="">description</data>
   <dta type="">description</data>
   ...
 </claim>
```

Can any one help me to create such XML using JAXB

Comment: check this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736343/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-java-object-to-xml-with-open-source-apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="claim")
public class Claim {
      @XmlElement(name="dta")
      List<Data> datas;
      //getter and setter
} 

public class Data {
  @XmlAttribute(name="type")
  String type;
  @XmlValue
  String description;
  //getter and setter 
}
```

and then to marshal:

```
 JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.getInstance(Claim.class);
 context.createMarshaller().marshal(claim);
```

If that doesn't work, try putting the annotations on the getter methods rather than the fields.

Comment: @Biju - If you do annotate the fields you should annotate your class with `@XmlAccesorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.